# I'm not be able to add LVM partition in iSCSI shared storage

Tags: lvm, iscsi, netapp

Hey guys currently I'm using proxmox 6.1 and i have created a cluster for high availability. I have one shared iSCSI storage from NetAPP, i want to create a LVM on that iSCSI storage but its asking for Base Volume, but i'm not be able to find that base volume. Please help me.

THANKS

Comment: Did you add iSCSI LUN to the Storage? Datacenter → Storage → iSCSI

Comment: Yess I already added to Storage now i'm trying to create lvm on that iscsi.

Comment: Do you mean it ask for Base storage (and not Base Volume)?

Comment: No it is asking for base volume.

Comment: I see. But if you define Base storage, Base volume will be filled automatically.  Did you select for Base Storage the ID of iSCSI?

Comment: Yee i filled everything but its not coming.